# Abnormal Voltage drop reading, 4 wire vs 3 wire, Singled ended input

Tags: single-ended

I have been given a measurement circuit that is measuring voltage drop across a switch. The idea is that it uses the 4 wire method for measuring resistance. However for our purpose we are not measuring current and are only concerning ourselves with voltage drop.

Using this method we have a repeat-ability issues (Gauge R&R). The reading can be any where from 30mV to 150mV, over 12 repetitions. I believe this is because the 0V/VCC Sense lead is floating away from 0V at the divider. If I tie the 0V sense directly to the 0V at the PLC the repeat-ability issue goes away and I get between 15mV - 21mV.

Would I be correct in thinking that a 3 wire method with no separate sense lead for 0V would make more sense given that the PLC input is single ended?

Note PLC input is a [Click C0-04AD-2](https://www.automationdirect.com/adc/Shopping/Catalog/Programmable_Controllers/CLICK_Series_PLCs_(Stackable_Micro_Brick)/Analog_I-z-O/C0-04AD-2)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRcnW5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Sch comment: Try to avoid crossing ground wires.  If a pin is connected to ground (or power), then put a ground (or power) symbol on it, and leave off the wires.  This produces schematics that are much easier to read, and as a result, you'll get more responses.  You may also discover someting about your circuit that you have overlooked...

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen What does a Power Symbol look like? I have never seen one. As for the grounds that were not using the ground symbol that was done on purpose as it was relevant to the question.

Comment: An example of ground and power symbols (googled):  http://www.altium.com/documentation/sites/default/files/wiki_attachments/250051/PowerNets1-highlight.png  The ground nets are circled.  Power nets include "5V" and "3V3".  Like the ground symbols, by convention, the power symbols connect to all other similarly-named power symbols circuit-wide.  If you include redundant wires in your circuit, then you should provide a label indicating why (your intentions).  Or group wires that are part of a physical cable, if you need to convey that.  This was done for some nets above, not all.

Comment: Just looking at that linked image again.  It's a poor example, as similarly-named power ports should used the same symbol shape.  This was not done in the cited example for the ground nets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not call the second one "three wire" because that name is used for other purposes.

Your circuits do not appear to do anything useful- at best they will output some weighted sum of the voltages at the ends of the switch.

What I think you need is the **difference** between the two sense wires, precisely canceling out the common mode voltage introduced by the 100mA through the force wires (and any variations thereof).

This can be accomplished with a [differential amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_amplifier), which is easy because your source impedances are very low so a single op-amp and four resistors will work. You can also get some gain so the ADC input will be less critical. However I suggest using a better op-amp than the LM358- it has a relatively high Vos spec. A single-supply precision op-amp would be much better. [LT1006](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1006fa.pdf) is one, but there are others.

[image]

Comment: What is a 3 wire then?

Comment: 3-wire resistance measuring is when you assume that at least two of the three wires running to the unknown resistance are the same resistance (most true if they come off the same reel and are installed beside each other so they are the same length and temperature). The resistance can be compensated by a few different means.. For example grounding one wire, applying current I through a second wire (and measuring the voltage at the remote end wrt ground) and applying -2I through the third wire. The voltage drops dude to wire resistance then (ideally) cancel out.

Comment: 2/2 it can also be done with one current source and two measurements, with some calculation. One wire is used as a sense wire with almost no current flowing. The voltages measured are I*(Rx + 2*R) and I*R, so you need to subtract double the measurement on the sense wire. Since R can be expected to change but slowly heavy digital filtering can be imposed on the latter, so the noise does not need to increase by the 280%+ you might expect.